# Browser-sync not opening index.php (using Gulp)

Tags: php, gulp, xampp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I am having an issue where browsersync does not find/open my index.php file.

The relevant parts of my gulp file are as follows:

```
const browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();
const php = require('gulp-connect-php');

// Configure PHP server
gulp.task('php', function(){
    php.server({base:'./', port:8010, keepalive:true});
});


// Inject php config into browserSync task
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy:'localhost:8000',
        port: 8080,
        baseDir: './',
        open:true,
        notify:false
  });
});


// Watch files
function watchFiles() {
  gulp.watch("./scss/**/*", css);
  gulp.watch(["./js/**/*", "!./js/**/*.min.js"], js);
  gulp.watch("./**/*.php", browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch("./**/*.html", browserSync.reload);
}


const watch = gulp.series(build, gulp.parallel(watchFiles, browserSync.reload));

// Export tasks
exports.watch = watch;
```

**My console output when 'Gulp watch' is run looks like this:**

[image: cmd output]

**The page never opens in the browser.**

Any advice as to why it is getting hung up on browser-sync?

Also, browsersync works when run directly in the cmd with:

```
browser-sync start --proxy "localhost/BtcMiningContracts" --files "*.php, *.html, css/*.css, ./js/**/*"
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many hours of searching have resulted in a working answer.
For anyone else experiencing the same issue, the updated code is below:

```
const browserSync = require("browser-sync");
const php = require('gulp-connect-php');

// Configure PHP server
gulp.task('connect-sync', function() {
  php.server({}, function (){
    browserSync({
      proxy: '127.0.0.1:8000'
    });
  });
 
  gulp.watch('**/*.php').on('change', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
  });
});

// Watch files
function watchFiles() {
  gulp.watch("./scss/**/*", css);
  gulp.watch(["./js/**/*", "!./js/**/*.min.js"], js);
  gulp.watch("./**/*.php").on('change', function () {
    browserSync.reload()});
}
```

**This works with scss**
hope it helps somebody out :)